# Angular 6 Failed to compile with Javascript code, but compiles with update

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

sorry for the rough title. No concise way to explain this one in the title.

Here's what is happening: I write javascript code in my Typescript Angular 6 application.

```
let dropdown = document.getElementById("filter-selection");
selectedFilter = dropdown.options[dropdown.selectedIndex].value;
```

The syntax highlighter highlights this, and marks it as an error. I run `ng serve` and get a failed to compile error because of the use of javascript HTMLElement.

If I replace the code to be as follows:

```
// let dropdown = document.getElementById("filter-selection");
selectedFilter = 'testing'; // dropdown.options[dropdown.selectedIndex].value;
```

The code (obviously) compiles just fine. Now, here's where things get interesting... If I **leave ng serve up and running**, edit the code back to its original state, and save the file, I get the same error logged, but the application compiles successfully and runs without any problems.

Can someone explain this? Has anyone else seen this behavior?

Edit: This behavior persists with or without the `--prod` flag.

Comment: If the CLI served your files once, and you edit them to get an error, instead of serving your new files, it will serve the previous ones (in cases the error isn't messing with the build, like this one). This isn't possible when you haven't served yet, since you don't have a previous version of your compiled files.

Comment: Do you want to resolve your error too, or was your question just about why the error isn't blocking your build in certain cases ?

Comment: It isn't serving the new files, the edited code comes through and changes the page after saving.

Comment: @trichetriche I'm able to resolve the error on my own, I'm just wondering about the angular cli behavior on this

Comment: I just tested this again, the source gets updated when I save between the two changes shown in the original question.

Comment: And if you change the text, does it gets updated ?

Comment: Yes, it does. The webpack as well as the application's behavior reflects the change

Comment: Then I don't exactly know what's happening, I had seen this behavior once and concluded what I've told you. Sorry I can't answer : maybe open an issue on Angular's repo to get an answer ?

Comment: Thanks for trying anyway. Yeah I'll leave the question here open for a little while, and see if anyone knows. Otherwise I think it may be a question for the source, yes.

Comment: @trichetriche if you're curious https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/11689